# JavaScript code to read the latest values from a json file that keeps getting updated every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am very new to JavaScript and trying to display the latest values from a .json file, that keeps getting updated every 10 seconds, into a HTML page. I am reading the file every 10 seconds as well, but I am not getting the latest values from the file. I am getting values which are 50 to 60 seconds older.

I have tried disabling the browser cahche in chrome but still the same issue. Can somebody please help on this?

My JavaScript code to read the json file is as follows:

```
function readJsonFile(callback) {
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/PersonalProject/filename.json');
 request.onload = function() {
  if(request.status>=100 && request.status<=100) {
   //perform some operation
   callback(request.responseText);
  }
  else{
   //perform some operation
   callback('FAILED');
  }
 };
 request.onerror = function() {
  console.error('Connection error');
 };
 request.send();
}


setInterval(function(){
 readJsonFile(function(stat){
  console.log(stat);
 });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: did you try checking the network calls and the response in network tab.

Comment: Yes, network calls seem fine with Status 200

Comment: the response, are they updated values ?

Comment: No, the response also are not updated values.

Comment: the problem might be with caching.

Comment: Ya even I thought the same and even tried disabling the cache from Developer Tools > Network > Disable Cache. But this is not working. Any other solution/alternative approach?

Comment: try adding `request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');` before `request.send();`

Comment: also disabling cache from Developer Tools > Network > Disable Cache will work only if you have not closed dev tools when the request is made, if you not getting updated values, you might have a caching in backend.

Comment: Tried adding request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'); but no luck. Even tried with request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store'); but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a timestamp as a parameter in your request to avoid the navigator cache:

```
...
let ms = Date.now();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/PersonalProject/filename.json?ms' + ms);
...
```

I do that any time i need to update js and css files when requested from the html header and it works